# Firebase and vendor files e.g bower_dependencies

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I understand Firebase Hosting is for, well, Hosting code files.

However, is there a way that I can ignore certain dependencies during deployment, but have Firebase run an install (like `bower install`) of them when the deployed code hits the server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run any further deployment tasks on server when deploying to Firebase storage.

I would use Gulp/Grunt build task which can run prior to deployment and replace all bower_dependencies with its CDN alternatives. This will save you some storage on the hosting as well as speed up your site a bit...

Alternatively you can use Gulp/Grunt to build your own dependecies from bower components which can be deployed to the server.

Comment: I don't know if Firebase Hosting has storage caps, therefore saving hosting storage isn't an issue.